# Merging two dataframes based on column values available in both databases, where column name is not known

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Here is my code. Basically, I am trying to figure out common rows based on a column called 'PolicyNum' (which has to be a variable, and therefore I cannot use df.PolicyNum.isin method).

while you can suggest a better way to do it, I am also wondering why would the length of the two dataframes (printing in lines 11 and 12) be different?

```
import pandas as pd

def getPreparedDataForComparison( baseDataFrame, secondaryDataFrame, sourceName, indexKey):
    baseDataFrameCommon = baseDataFrame[(baseDataFrame[indexKey].isin(secondaryDataFrame[indexKey]) == False)]
    baseDataFrameCommon['COMBO'] = baseDataFrameCommon.apply(lambda x :','.join(x.astype(str)),axis=1)
    baseDataFrameCommon['DataSource'] = sourceName
    return baseDataFrameCommon

def compareDataFrames(dataframe1, dataframe2, indexKey):
    dataframe1Common = getPreparedDataForComparison(dataframe1, dataframe2, 'TXT', indexKey)
    dataframe2Common = getPreparedDataForComparison(dataframe2, dataframe1, 'SQL', indexKey)
    print(len(dataframe1Common))
    print(len(dataframe2Common))

def sampleData1():
    cols = ['PolicyNum','firsttransactiondate','subsequentbonustotalcumulative','subsequentpremiumtotalcumulative','totalautocumulative','totalautoposteffectivedatecumulative','totalpartialcumulative','totalpartialposteffectivedatecumulative']
    sourceData  = [ ('E001','#1985-01-01#',100,100,100,100,100,100),
                    ('E002','#1985-01-01#',200,200,200,200,200,200),
                    ('E003','#1985-01-01#',100,100,100,100,100,100),
                    ('E004','#1985-01-01#',100,100,100,100,100,100),
                    ('E005','#1985-01-01#',100,100,100,100,100,100),
                    ('E201','#1985-01-01#',100,100,100,100,100,100),
                    ('E202','#1985-01-01#',100,100,100,100,100,100),
                    ('1006','#1985-01-01#',100,100,100,100,100,100),
                    ('1007','#1985-01-01#',100,100,100,100,100,100),
                    ('1008','#1985-01-01#',100,100,100,100,100,100),]
    x = pd.DataFrame(sourceData,columns=cols)
    return x

def sampleData2():
    cols = ['PolicyNum','firsttransactiondate','subsequentbonustotalcumulative','subsequentpremiumtotalcumulative','totalautocumulative','totalautoposteffectivedatecumulative','totalpartialcumulative','totalpartialposteffectivedatecumulative']
    sourceData  = [ ('E001','#1985-01-01#',100,300,100,100,100,400),
                    ('E002','#1985-01-01#',200,200,200,200,200,200),
                    ('E005','#1989-01-01#',100,100,100,100,100,100),
                    ('E105','#1989-01-01#',100,100,100,100,100,100),
                    ('1106','#1985-01-01#',100,100,100,100,900,100),
                    ('1006','#1985-01-01#',100,100,100,100,900,100),
                    ('1007','#1985-01-01#',100,100,100,100,100,100),]
    x = pd.DataFrame(sourceData,columns=cols)
    return x

compareDataFrames(sampleData1(),sampleData2(),'PolicyNum')
```

Comment: Will `PolicyNum` always be in the same column? If so, you could try `df1[df1.columns[index_of_col]].isin(df2[df2.columns[index_of_col]])`

Comment: That is my problem! PolicyNum has to be a variable!

Comment: Well whatever it is, if it's being set to a column name of your dataframe, whether it's `foo` or `17.891231`, df.columns will figure it out. So long as it always winds up being the first column, `DataFrame[DataFrame.columns[0]]` will select that column regardless of what the column header is, so you're free to use `pd.Series.isin()` on that series.

Comment: Couldn't you just do an inner join to get the `PolicyNum` that exists in both dataframes? Something like `df1.merge(df2, on='PolicyNum', how='inner')`

Comment: Hey @Simon, that was one of the thoughts. But merge will not give me what I am looking for. Merge will merely add columns.  I necessarily want two rows each for same PolicyNums. My question still remains unanswered though. Why are the counts different. Thanks.

Comment: @ALollz - That didnt solve my problem. I still have length mismatches for dataframe1Common and dataframe2Common

Comment: Well, I don't know. If you do `df1 = sampleData1()
df2 = sampleData2()` and `sum(df1[df1.columns[0]].isin(df2[df2.columns[0]]))` and `sum(df2[df2.columns[0]].isin(df1[df1.columns[0]]))` I get 5 in each case, indicating that there are 5 shared things in the PolicyNum column for the two sample DataFrames you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way I think, but this is what I landed up doing.

pandas junkies can have a dig at it.

```
def getPreparedDataForComparison( baseDataFrame, secondaryDataFrame, sourceName, indexKey):
    baseDataFrame['DataSource'] = sourceName
    baseDataFrame['Common'] = np.where((baseDataFrame[indexKey].isin( list(secondaryDataFrame[indexKey]))),True,False)
    baseDataFrameCommon = baseDataFrame.loc[baseDataFrame['Common'] == True]
    baseDataFrameCommon.drop(['Common'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    baseDataFrameCommon['COMBO'] = baseDataFrameCommon.apply(lambda x :','.join(x.astype(str)),axis=1)
    baseDataFrame = None
    secondaryDataFrame = None    
    return baseDataFrameCommon
```